# Monitor multiple file sizes and export result to csv every minute using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

What I am attempting to do is read the file size from 4 files every minute and then output the results to a CSV file. I would like each file size written to their own column. I have attempted this with the code below but I am not getting the results I need. When the file sizes are written to the CSV they are added to a single column, each size on their own row.
If I expand my array ($Process) to two records it forces all of the file lengths in the first record to the first row, each in their own column (which is what I want).
The second record does the same.
Is there any way to force a single record to one line and their values in their own columns by making an adjustment to the code? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
$Csv = 'c:\users\rob\LogFileSize.csv'
$today = get-date -f "ddd"
$day = $today.ToLower()
$date = Get-Date
$numColstoExport=5

$a = dir C:\RTscada\bin\ErrorLogs\error1_Log_$day.txt
$a | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileLength -Value Length
$b = dir C:\RTscada\bin\ErrorLogs\error2_Log_$day.txt
$b| Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileLength -Value Length
$c = dir C:\RTscada\bin\ErrorLogs\error3_Log_$day.txt
$c | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileLength -Value Length
$d = dir C:\RTscada\bin\ErrorLogs\error4_Log_$day.txt
$d | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name FileLength -Value Length


$error1 = $a.Length
$error2 = $b.Length
$error3 = $c.Length
$error4 = $d.Length

# Array of date and file lengths
$Process = @($date, $error1, $error2, $error3, $error4)

$holdarr=@()
$pNames=@("Date", "Error1", "Error2","Error2","Error4")
foreach ($row in $Process){
    $obj = new-object PSObject
    for ($i=0;$i -lt $numColstoExport; $i++){
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $pNames[$i] -Value $row[$i]
        }
    $holdarr+=$obj
    $obj=$null
}

$holdarr | export-csv $Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function MonitorLogFiles  {

    Param(
        $LogFiles,
        $Csv
    )

    $FirstCsvLine = 'Date'

    foreach ($LogFile in $LogFiles) {
        $FirstCsvLine = $FirstCsvLine + ",$(Split-Path $LogFile -leaf)"
    }

    $FirstCsvLine | Out-File $Csv  -Encoding UTF8


    while ($True) {

            $CurrentCsvLine = (Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").ToString()

            foreach ($LogFile in $LogFiles) {

                $Size = (Get-Item $LogFile).Length / 1KB

                $CurrentCsvLine = $CurrentCsvLine + ",$Size KB"

             }

            $CurrentCsvLine | Out-File $Csv  -append  -Encoding UTF8
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
           }

}

MonitorLogFiles -LogFiles C:\test.txt,C:\Test2.txt -Csv c:\test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$holdarr|Select-Object -Property Name, Value | Export-Csv $Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Note: Whatever desired columns you wish to select , take all of them in the *select-object*.

Hope it helps.